# Why am I getting double like output in Log4J?

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I am working on a Java Spring project and I want to log WARNS from every package and only INFO from my packages.

I don't know why Log4J is giving me double line output for my packages.

Can someone please tell me why

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>


    <logger name="com.xxxxx.mongodb">
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <priority value="WARN"/>
        <appender-ref ref="console"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
additivity="false"
```

attribute to the logger what is producing double output.

Answer (score 2):

Because your logger inherits the appenders from root logger.

The [docs](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) for log4j state:

> The output of a log statement of logger C will go to all the appenders
>   in C and its ancestors. This is the meaning of the term "appender
>   additivity".
>
> However, if an ancestor of logger C, say P, has the additivity flag
>   set to false, then C's output will be directed to all the appenders in
>   C and its ancestors upto and including P but not the appenders in any
>   of the ancestors of P.
>
> Loggers have their additivity flag set to true by default.